# Change "jquery" function to "jquery wordpress" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have the following jquery function:

```
function lookup(inputString, divid, filename) {
   if(inputString.length == 0) {
      $('#'+divid).fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
   } else {
        if (inputString.length > 2) {
          $.post(filename, {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
             $('#'+divid).fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
             $('#'+divid).html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
          });
        }
   }
}
```

It's working great, but I want to use it in an wordpress theme. Any Idea how to change the function, that it can be used with wordpress?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in Wordperss? Just make sure you have JQuery included in Wordpress...

Comment: It's not a "jQuery" function, it's a "JavaScript" function that uses the jQuery library.

Comment: the question was not "too broad". The first answer was the correct solution, so it was well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, jQuery is conflict with wordpress since both are using `$`, you can try to change `$` to `jQuery` in your code.

```
function lookup(inputString, divid, filename) {
   if(inputString.length == 0) {
      jQuery('#'+divid).fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
   } else {
        if (inputString.length > 2) {
          jQuery.post(filename, {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
             jQuery('#'+divid).fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
             jQuery('#'+divid).html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
          });
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer. Have to change all my scripts ;-) Will mark it as answer as soon as possible!